# Contraction of particle の to ん before nouns in colloquial Japanese

Tags: set-phrases, colloquial-language, particle-の, contractions

I am familiar with contraction of の to ん before です (and variants で, だ, でした etc) but I noticed that の is also contracted before 家 in spoken set-phrases like あたしんち and おれんち.

Are there any other instances where の is contracted before some particular nouns? I remember hearing おれんとこ in some anime/jdrama but I might have misheard.

Also, are there any dialects that utilize these types of contractions more frequently than the other colloquial dialects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Chakoshi](http://tell.fll.purdue.edu/chakoshi/public.html) to the rescue! (Chakoshi is a tool for searching both the Aozora and conversational Japanese corpora at Nagoya University.)

A quick search for a "[noun]ん[noun]" pattern in the conversational corpus gives 262 results, most of which are what you are asking about. Broken down, there's actually not much variety in the nouns that follow ん:

> とき (99): 高校**ん**とき, 研修**ん**とき, 外出**ん**とき, …
>
> とこ(ろ) (78): そこ**ん**とこ, こっち**ん**とこ, 今**ん**とこ, ほか**ん**とこ, …
>
> 中 (62): 頭**ん**中, 山**ん**中, 電車**ん**中, …
>
> ち (11): おれ**ん**ち, おまえ**ん**ち, 人**ん**ち, …

This contraction is present in both masculine and feminine speech. I can't think of any other phrases offhand that use ん this way, but I can't say that means they're not out there. If you can think of some, please put in a comment.

As far as dialectical variation goes, the Chakoshi corpus [covers a fairly wide range of speakers](http://tell.fll.purdue.edu/chakoshi/meidai-chuui.html), but I would have to do a deeper analysis on the results to find out if there are any trends.

Comment: There's one instance of の->ん contraction before a personal pronoun that I can think of: [あんにゃろ](http://www.google.com/search?q=+%22%E3%81%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%82%83%E3%82%8D%22) (あの野郎), [こんにゃろ](http://www.google.com/search?q=+%22%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%82%83%E3%82%8D%22) (この野郎). I don't know if it counts as a "pure" contraction from の to ん, because the "n" consonant of ん is seeping into the next sound "や"..