# Nominalization with 「ん」and its use for humans (「そんなん入れるよーじゃおしまいだな」)

Tags: grammar, particles, nouns, morphology

Taken from 「イエスタデイをうたって3」:

Three guys of an indie band are having a talk about the current situation of their band and the place where they usually have their performances. While discussing their upcoming performance one of the guys mentions that a famous high-schooler-band will have a gig in the same club at the same night, so they expect it to be crowded. After hearing that they say:

> 「ウソ　やつ　そんな　若ぇの？」
>
> 「あのコヤも**そんなん**入れるよーじゃおしまいだな」

I already checked out this post: [What are the rules for substituting の with ん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5780/what-are-the-rules-for-substituting-%e3%81%ae-with-%e3%82%93)

In accordance, I think that 「**ん**」here is just a phonological phenomenon, but with the same „ability“ to nominalize adjectives as 「**の**」. Jisho lists 「**こんな**」as pre-noun adjective, yet I assume that it can be nominalized with 「**の**」like other adjectives as well. Therefore the 「**そんなん**」in the sentence above would be a noun (?).

If  the above is correct, my question would be in how far 「**の**」can be used for people without being inherently derogatory? While the statement above is not friendly in general, I was thinking about a dialogue like:

> 「どんな男性が好きですか？」
>
> 「優しいの」

Would this answer be acceptable? Even if it is acceptable are there more appropriate alternatives?

Please let me know if my conclusions about nominalization are blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this そんなん is a colloquial version of そんなの, which in this context means "such a guy".

This use of の/ん as a pronoun for a person sounds rough and/or arrogant. The first example is natural since he is already referred to as やつ. On the other hand, the second example sounds condescending and unnatural. You usually have to say 優しい人(が好き)です or 優しい男性(が好き)です instead.

See also: [When can you use the の particle to replace a noun?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58550/5010)