# What does "とこの" mean here?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

Sentence is:

> うん俺の嫌いな杉木さんとこの一人息子な

Translation is:

> Yup. The only son of the Sugiki I hate.

What does とこの do here?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/contraction-of-particle-%e3%81%ae-to-%e3%82%93-before-nouns-in-colloquial-japanese

Answer (score 5):

杉木さんとこの is semantically the same as 杉木さん**の**ところの ("of Sugiki's family").

- とこ is colloquialism for ところ ("place", or in this case "house" or "family").
- The particle の before ところ often turns into ん in speech (e.g., 彼のとこ → 彼んとこ, あいつのとこ → あいつんとこ), but when there is already ん before it, the double ん will be contracted to single ん. For example 奥さんのとこ(ろ) contracts to 奥さんとこ, not 奥さんんとこ .